# Как скачать zip файл который приходит с сервера?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, zip

я отравляю c js запрос на php файл

и получаю результат (на картинки написано что приходит), это zip архив, вопрос как его скачать на комп

я отравляю c js запрос на php файл

```
    $.ajax({
     url: '/app/app.php',
     method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data:{
            method: "download",
            request_type: typeDownload
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Потом в php отправляю запрос на основной сервер

$download =sendUploadMaterials('https://serverURL',array("request_type"=>$_POST["request_type"]));
print_r($download);

и получаю результат (на картинки написано что приходит), это zip архив, вопрос как его скачать на комп

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: function sendUploadMaterials($url, $json) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$_SESSION['token'],
    ));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

вот post запрос на сервер

Comment: Поместите код из комментария в вопрос, не забудьте его отформатировать либо кнопкой вставки кода, либо вручную добавив 4 пробела перед каждой строкой, для того чтобы править вопрос под ним есть ссылка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1532923/edit)